# whole Ubuntu freezes when running actionlistener

Tags: java

My too simple Swing code is causing the whole system to freeze. I'm learning java still :)
this is the `actionEvent` that is causing the problem

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String username = usernameField.getText();
    String password = passwordField.getText();

    System.out.println("hej");
}
```

I haven't wrote anything in there yet(still testing) because obviously it is in the code here in the class xD

```
public class NewAccount implements ActionListener {

static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
static JButton createAccountButton = new JButton();
static JButton haveAnAccount = new JButton();
static JLabel usernameLabel = new JLabel();
static JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel();
static JTextField usernameField = new JTextField();
static JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField();


NewAccount() {

    frame = new JFrame();
    createAccountButton = new JButton("Create account");
    haveAnAccount = new JButton("Already have an account?");
    usernameLabel = new JLabel("New username");
    passwordLabel = new JLabel("New Password");
    usernameField = new JTextField(20);
    passwordField = new JPasswordField(20);

    //Frame
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(400, 250);
    frame.setTitle("Create new account");

    //Buttons
    frame.add(createAccountButton);
    createAccountButton.setLocation(20, 130);
    createAccountButton.setSize(230, 30);
    createAccountButton.setFocusable(false);
    createAccountButton.addActionListener(new NewAccount());

    frame.add(haveAnAccount);
    haveAnAccount.setLocation(20, 170);
    haveAnAccount.setSize(230, 30);
    haveAnAccount.setFocusable(false);

    //Labels
    frame.add(usernameLabel);
    usernameLabel.setLocation(20, 20);
    usernameLabel.setSize(130, 30);

    frame.add(passwordLabel);
    passwordLabel.setLocation(20, 50);
    passwordLabel.setSize(130, 30);

    //Fields
    frame.add(usernameField);
    usernameField.setLocation(150, 20);
    usernameField.setSize(165, 25);

    frame.add(passwordField);
    passwordField.setLocation(150, 50);
    passwordField.setSize(165, 25);


}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String username = usernameField.getText();
    String password = passwordField.getText();

    System.out.println("hej");
}
```

}

I have no idea what is wrong with it but when I delete the actionlistener it works without freezing my whole system.

Comment: what do you mean: "freezing my whole system"?

Comment: I mean the whole Ubuntu system freezes and I can do nothing but hold press on the power button until it turns off

Comment: Please don't add an answer to your question by editing it in. If your question has been solved by an answer, you can accept it, if you solved the problem yourself you can [write your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept that.

Comment: ok, sorry I am new here, I'll add the answer

Answer (score 0):

> createAccountButton.addActionListener(new NewAccount());

Congratulations, you created an infinite loop. That eats your memory.

Maybe you mean to pass `this`?

Comment: yeah that could have worked too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```java
createAccountButton.addActionListener(new NewAccount());
```

to

```java
createAccountButton.addActionListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

it was a simple mistake but took me so many hours that I had to make a question here. the only problem was to put this

```
createAccountButton.addActionListener(new NewAccount());
```

before setting it's bounds and location. hope if anyone had the same problem sees this.